# Tweak CRM Sitemap to have different URL navigations for different environments

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, crm-sitemap

We want to have different Sitemap subarea Url, so that the Sitemap can be independent of environments & worryfree when we refresh the environments from higher region to lower. Even deployments can be error free & can avoid manual step in post deployment activity.

Dev:

```
<SubArea Id="nav_hub" ResourceId="Hub_SubArea_Title" DescriptionResourceId="Hub_SubArea_Description" 
   ToolTipResourseId="Hub_SubArea_ToolTip" Icon="/_imgs/Hub_32.png" 
     Url="http://mydevhub.com/home.aspx" AvailableOffline="false" />
```

UAT:

```
<SubArea Id="nav_hub" ResourceId="Hub_SubArea_Title" DescriptionResourceId="Hub_SubArea_Description" 
    ToolTipResourseId="Hub_SubArea_ToolTip" Icon="/_imgs/Hub_32.png" 
       Url="http://myuathub.com/home.aspx" AvailableOffline="false" />
```

Any idea to do that?

Comment: Have you tried referencing a web resource that has Javascript to dynamically set the URL based off a setting held within CRM?

Comment: @HadleyPettigrew thank you, this is what I ended up. also Sitemap should evolve like Ribbon/command bar for more control with custom code, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this workaround as we cannot pass dynamic variable url to Sitemap.

1.Created a Sub-Area with url to custom HTML web resource as below:

```
$webresource:pub/Scripts/External/navigation.html
```

2.Just used the below content to open a new window based on org url:

```
<html><head>
<script src="../../../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
var crmUrl = parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();

if (crmUrl.indexOf('devinstance.crm.dynamics.com') > 0)
            parent.window.open('http://mydevhub.com/home.aspx');

if (crmUrl.indexOf('uatinstance.crm.dynamics.com') > 0)
            parent.window.open('http://myuathub.com/home.aspx');

</script>
</head><body>
</body></html>
```

Comment: We can store the required destination url as a key value pair in a custom configuration entity and each environment can have its unique value. This has to be maintained in each environment and can be queried in above web resource instead of hard coding.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else lands here (and since I can't comment yet) the answer provided is deprecated.

The newer way of achieving this is

```
var globalContext = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext();
globalContext.getClientUrl();
```

([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/GetGlobalContext-ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx))

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question

Comment: @ArunVinoth I was referring to this part in your answer -
    parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();


Xrm.Page is deprecated and the recommended approach is now using Xrm.Utility